# variable list argument function returning address

Tags: c++

Hello guys my program is not printing the maximum value it is printing some garbage value or address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

int findmax(int, ...);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << findmax(9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29);
}

int findmax(int count, ...) {
    int max, val;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        max = va_arg(list, int);
        val = va_arg(list, int);
        if (max < val) max = val;
    }
    va_end(list);

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the line `max = va_arg(list, int);`.  You're looping over your arguments, so you need to call `va_arg` just *once* per trip through the loop.  By calling it twice, you're trying to fetch twice as many arguments as there are, with meaningless (and undefined) results.

Comment: ... and give `max` an initial (very low) value.

Comment: ... or fetch first argument and use it to initialize `max` and only afterwards iterate of the remaining arguments.

Comment: Unless you're really set on using a variable argument list, I'd consider passing a `std::initializer_list` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    max = va_arg(list, int);
    val = va_arg(list, int);
    if (max < val) max = val;
}
```

In this code you take two arguments but iterate the index by one. `va_arg` always takes the next element, so you end up with taking values beyond the variadic function argument list.

You may iterate by two elements, but this would require you to have even number of arguments, thus just declare a separate variable to store the `max` element:

```cpp
// std::numeric_limits is defined in <limits> header
auto max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
for (decltype(count) i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    auto val = va_arg(list, int);
    if (max < val)
        max = val;
}
```