# Why isn't initializer_list being deduced as an argument for a concept it matches?

Tags: c++, c++20, initializer-list, c++-concepts, template-argument-deduction

I was playing with concepts (I wanted to give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585447/variable-list-argument-function-returning-address) a C++ey answer) and came across a behavior with std::initializer_list that puzzles me.  Although the following code works:

```
#include<utility>
#include <limits>
#include<iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string_view>

template <class C>
struct iterable_sfinae
{
    template <class U>
    static auto check(U*u)->decltype(u->begin()!=u->end());

    template <class...>
    static void check(...);

    static constexpr bool value = !std::is_void_v<decltype(check((C*)0))>;
};

template <class C> 
static constexpr bool is_iterable_v = iterable_sfinae<C>::value;

template <class C> 
concept Iterable = iterable_sfinae<C>::value;

template <class N>
constexpr bool is_numeric_v = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<N>>::is_specialized;

template <class N>
concept Number = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<N>>::is_specialized;

// alternative 2
template <Iterable C>
auto findmax(C const &c)
requires is_numeric_v<decltype(*(c.begin()))>
{
   auto rv = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<decltype(*(c.begin()))>>::lowest();
   for (auto e: c)
       if (e > rv) rv = e;
   return rv;
}




int main() {
        
    std::vector<int> v = {9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29};
    std::cout << "using vector via concept: " << findmax(v) << '\n';
    
    std::initializer_list<int> il = {9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29};
    std::cout << "using initializer_list: " << findmax(il) << '\n';

    std::boolalpha(std::cout);
    std::cout << "initializer_list is iterable: " << is_iterable_v<std::initializer_list<int>> << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
using vector via concept: 422
using initializer_list: 422
initializer_list is iterable: true
```

But if I want to add

```
// alternative 3
std::cout << "using braced-init-list: " << findmax({9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29}) << '\n';
```

the program won't compile. The reason given by MSVC, gcc, and clang is "Couldn't deduce template argument". But if you add an overload for std::initializer_list, it does:

```
template <Number N>
auto findmax(std::initializer_list<N> const &c)
{         
   auto rv = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<decltype(*(c.begin()))>>::min();
   for (auto e: c)
       if (e > rv) rv = e;
   return rv;
}
```

Output:

```
using braced-init-list: 422
```

Now, cppreference says (at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) that

> A std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when...a braced-init-list is used...as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an std::initializer_list parameter.

`initializer_list` matches the Iterable concept, and the concept-based overload does, however, accept the explicitly-declared initializer_list variable.
, and this implies to me that the bare braced-init-list should generate an iniitalizer_list and select the concept-based overload. But it doesn't.
The concept-based overload accepts a std::initializer_list parameter, so why can't that overload deduce and create an initializer_list argument from the bare braced-init-list?

[The full code is here](https://godbolt.org/z/svfGqT88o),

---

So I found a workaround that underscores how weird this all is.  If we replace the `findmax` specialization for `initializer_list` with

```
template <class C>
inline std::initializer_list<C> const &make_il(std::initializer_list<C> const &i)
{
    return i;
}
```

we can clue in the main template to accept

```
// alternative 3
std::cout << "using make_il: " << findmax(make_il({9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29})) << '\n';
```

The "magic" of creating an initializer_list from a braced-init-list seems to only happen when `initializer_list` is mentioned explicitly, and not when looking up a generic template argument (even if it is constrained).  Why is that?

Comment: baiscally `{...}` is **not** `std::initilizer_list`

Comment: @appleapple That doesn't explain why it worked for the `initializer_list` overload and not the concept-based overload.

Comment: because compiler cannot determine T in that case.

Comment: @appleapple Why?

Comment: because it's no different there compare to, say, `std::vector`

Comment: @appleapple Yes it is...the Standard mentions initializer_list explicitly for braced-init-lists of function calls.   You see why a short, glib answer in the comments won't cut it, and an actual "answer" post is required?

Comment: I don't see it... T is definitely not *`std::initializer_list` parameter*,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247757/discussion-between-spencer-and-apple-apple).

Comment: and the example it too long, too. `template<typename T> void foo(T){}

int main() {
    foo({1,2,3});
}` is enough to illustrate the same situation.

Comment: Jarod42 It wasn't a hard error (as somehow `is_iterable_v<int>` was `true`), so I replaced it with something less ambitious (if imperfect) that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `{9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29}` is **not** implicitly  a `std::initializer_list`.

Its meaning and its type is intended to be contextually inferred from its usage.

- If you pass it to a function that expects a `std::initializer_list<int>`, then that's what it is.
- If you pass it to a function that expects a `std::array<int,10>`, then that's what it is.
- If you pass it to a function that expects an aggregate type, then that's what it is.

You, however, are passing it as a deduced template argument `template <Iterable C> auto findmax(C const &c)`

`findmax({9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29})` won't compile because the function relies on the call site to specify what type is being passed, and your call site is depending on the function to specify what type is being passed.

`std::initializer_list` isn't mentioned at either location, so the compiler does not know that you want `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: I added overloads for `std::vector` and `std::array` to the one I added for `std::initializer_list` and it wasn't ambiguous.  In fact, if I kept them and removed the `initializer_list` overload the code no longer compiled. So there's **something** special about `initializer list`.

Comment: @Spencer When you pass an `std::vector`, its overload is chosen. When you pass an `std::array`, its overload is chosen. *When you pass an `std::initializer_list`, its overload is chosen*. But `{9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29}` is none of these things.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  When you pass `{9, 255, 86, 4, 89, 6, 1, 422, 5, 29}` by itself, the `std::initializer_list` overload is chosen.  But neither the `std::vector` overload nor the `std::array` overload is.  So somewhere, the compiler is deciding "Oh, this is likely an initializer_list", in some special way that doesn't consider `vector`.

Comment: Yes, `std::initializer_list` is special. Overloads with it are sometimes preferred over other overloads, all other things being equal. This doesn't make it magical enough to make a template parameter deduce to `std::initializer_list` when a braced-init-list is used as an actual argument.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: `std::initializer_list` is not special, it is `{..}` construct which is.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. We're getting somewhere! A complete answer would explain why the magic happens in one place and not the other. There is probably language in the Standard that explains it. Or maybe a lacuna that implies it....

Comment: @Jarod42 It is special, there are many mentions of it in various part of the standard (the language part, not the library, and not specifically connected with the braced-init-list construct).

Answer (score 3):

`{..}` has no type and can only be deduced as `const T(&)[N]` or (const ref of) `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Type expected from `findmax` is not of the above form, it accepts `const T&`
`template <Iterable C> auto findmax(C const &c)`.